# Using a generic ViewModel

Tags: wpf, generics, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM App, but I want my ViewModel to be generic. What the app is suppose to do is take some Data and do CRUD operations on it without knowing the Type of the data it's getting at the compile-time. So I declared my ViewModel like this:

```
public class GenericViewModel<T> where T : class
{

    private void ConstructorBase()
    {
        Type theType = typeof(T);
        Properties = theType.GetProperties().ToList();
    }

    public GenericViewModel(DbContext _dbContextInsert) //pravi novi repository na osnovu DbContexta
    {
        ConstructorBase();
        _R = new RepositoryGlobal<T>(_dbContextInsert);
    }


    public T newT { get; set; }
    public T selectedT { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyInfo> Properties { get; set; }
    private RepositoryGlobal<T> _R;

}
```

Now, disregard almost everything you see inside it, the only important thing is that the Constructor is never reached. I set this ViewModel as the DataContext for the main window like this:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = new GenericViewModel<Person>(new PersonDbContext());
```

But when I put a breakpoint inside the ViewModel's constructor, the program never gets stopped.
Any ideas?

Comment: The PersonDbContext constructor or a static field of GenericViewModel or PersonDbContext probably crashes and break your class

Comment: I don't see any apparent reason why it shouldn't at least hit the breakpoint. Have you tried putting the breakpoint at this.DataContext = ... and stepping through?

Comment: And what happens when you set a breakpoint at InitializeComponent ?  Any plugins active, for instance for a DI container? Maybe you are using a different ctor.

Comment: To sum up: we don't have enough information to help you (full GenericViewModel  and PersonDbContext  code would be welcome)

Answer (score 1):

*Dependencies should be abstractions, not implementations.*

Your generic view model should **not** create it's own repository, instead you should pass in an instance of this **dependency** via the constructor.

```
public class GenericViewModel<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly IRepository<T> _Repository;

    public GenericViewModel(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _Repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}
```

You would then create an instance of your repository like so:

```
DbContext context = new PersonDbContext();
IRepository<Person> personRepo = new PersonRepository(context);
GenericViewModel<Person> personViewModel = new GenericViewModel<Person>(personRepo);
```

There, your View Model's dependencies are no longer tied to a specific implementation, your code is now far more adaptable to changes. Not to mention massively easier to test.

Comment: Yeah, I said 'disregard what is inside ViewModel' because that is not the problem. The problem is that the ViewModel never gets instantiated, even though I set it as DataContext of the MainWindow.
Thank you for the input, but it still doesn't solve my problem.